# Laravel return related model beside the main model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `User` model which has the following method:

```php
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

And also `Article` model, which has:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I want to return a list of users that contains each of thems articles. So with this one:

```php
// only returns list of users
return $user = User::all();
```

And with the following:

```php
$user = User::all();
foreach ($user[0]->articles as $article) {
    return $article;
}
```

I only get the first one's articles. Is there any way (in laravel) to retrieve the whole list with each one's articles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call with method to eager load all articles.

```
$user = User::with('articles')->get();
dd($user);
```

or if you want to lazy load then.

```
$user = User::get();
dd($user->articles());
```

you can use select() to select specific columns - for example

```php
$user = User::select('name','email')->get();
```

if you want to select specific columns in with() then

```php
$user = User::with(['articles' => function($query){
    $query->select('id','title');
}])->get();
```

or

```php
$user = User::with(['articles' => function($query){
    $query->select('id','title');
}])->select('name','email')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find it in the laravel documentation. Is there any doc for it?

Comment: Also, how can I filter the columns? (for example, I don't want to retrieve the password)

Comment: Hello @VahidNajafi maybe new documentation missing that features but you can lookup over any old version documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: All eloquent features still same in new version. just added new features.

Comment: also you can use https://summerblue.github.io/laravel5-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thank you, but you're only retrieving user table. How about with articles and specified columns?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you return inside the foreach loop, which will stop the loop after the first iteration, and therefore only return the first article.

If you want to show the user and articles in a JSON response, you should look at [Eloquent Resources, Writing Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources), especially the *Relationships* part of that chapter.

Comment: If you want me to elaborate on this, you need to describe your use case better. Do you want this as a JSON result, where you have all the user data, with articles?